# Distance Among Guide Lines in Figma?

Tags: adobe-xd, figma

so I am using Figma for now because Adobe XD will no more free. I am curious if there is a configuration to show distance among guide lines in Figma like Adobe XD has?
[image]

Above is the illustration. Thanks in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can **Press Alt** and **hover over any element** with your mouse.
Works in both XD and Figma.

Answer (score 0):

For easy steps, just make a frame or a slice, then fit the height of your frame/slice until it's cover all of the distance among guidelines.

The second option is to make a copy of the guidelines, or you can make a straight line then copy it using the alt+click on the line. Figma will show the distance among the copied line to the real line/guidelines.